# Connection Pool Empty Hibernate 4, but Unable to Find the Culprit

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, transactions, sql-server-2012, connection-pooling

I'm monitoring the SQL database for connections every 5 minutes. For days it'll hover around 5 connections (my idle) then suddenly I'm at 50. Obviously this is a recursive issue because I can't see why I would jump from 5 to 50 within 5 minutes with zero traffic.

I'm using Hibernate 4 and Tomcat and I know of an issue in Hibernate that was patched in 4.3.2, but I'm on 4.3.5

**More details:**
The pool empty event happens every day at exactly 7:13:20PM... Sounds too automatic. I am using Quartz and it runs every 1 minute, but I can't see how they're related.

My properties:

```
jmxEnabled = true
initialSize = 5
maxActive = 50
minIdle = 5
maxIdle = 25
maxWait = 10000
maxAge = 10 * 60000
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
validationQueryTimeout = 3
validationInterval = 15000
testOnBorrow = true
testWhileIdle = true
testOnReturn = false
jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Environment:

- Tomcat 7.0.59
- java 1.7.0 update 76
- SQL Server 2012

**More information:**
I reduced the quartz job frequency to every 5 minutes. The event still took place when I loaded a page/view in the application. This was roughly at 7:14 PM. 
I'm on the verge of downgrading to hibernate 3.

**Update**
Today I reloaded the application in Tomcat Manager at 6:50 PM, but the event still took place.
[Thread Dump](http://pastebin.com/z5fZ2jKk)

Comment: I removed the parent->child tomcat daemon and now I only have 10 appropriately named quartz-workers.

Comment: What type of connection pool are you using?  I found that sometimes trying out Hikari or another CP provider can lend itself to debug statements to track these types of problems down.  Might be a good idea to give it a go in a test environment.

Comment: @bphilinyc I have not tried another provider besides tomcat. I did, however, deploy to QA environment, but did not experience the same issue. Very localized and most likely external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to first thank everyone for contributing your answers. Like @JensSchauder had suggested I was working on trying to isolate the problem. Wondering why I didn't have the problem in QA, but did so in production.

Even though I followed up with my Network Operations team, no one hit on it until I finally got the logs I was needing.

We use a product called Alert Logic to scan and identify security vulnerabilities, but unfortunately it wasn't discovered to be the culprit until I was able to trace the Apache access logs to an IP address. whois identified the IP originating from the Alert Logic software out of a Rackspace host.

The application server was new and consisted of a new architecture image. It turns out Alert Logic was hitting upon a vulnerability. This then led to a connection pool emptying (bailing?)

Until mid-last week, I had no idea Alert Logic was even in the equation. In fact, now, I'm working with Network Operations to get a better observation of the product since it was lapsed.

Later this week, I'll publish the findings of the vulnerability while in QA (since patching production was priority).

Answer (score 2):

Ah those kind of bugs are fun. Obviously there is no way we can point you to the exact culprint (except when somebody digs up a bug in the libs you mentioned), so lets see how you can debug this. Approximatly from easy to hard to do, although the details depend on your environment.

1. You have very helpful information: The problem happens always at the same time. This hints at two options: either one of your jobs that you run with Quartz eats up connections, or something (possible external) is happening at that time causing your code to eat up connections. Obviously you should check your job configurations and cron jobs or jobs configured inside the database or similar for potential culprits. Note that they might start quite some time earlier and just arrive at that critical state later on, so the job might start 2hours earlier for all we know.
2. Check your logs and the system logs and the database logs for anything that happens at that time or some time earlier.
3. Double check everything that gets a connection if it always returns the connection. Especially when exceptions get thrown. One classical way to fail at that is a construction like this (java like pseudo code):

   ```
   Connection con;

   try {
       con = getConnection();
       Statement = stmnt = con.createStatement();
       ....
   } finally (Exception ex){
       if (stmnt != null) stmnt.close();
       if (con != null) con.close(); // this will never happen if stmnt.close throws an exceptions

   }
   ```
4. Establish logging that let you see when exactly connection don't  get returned. Everything that start anything in your application should go through some kind of wrapper (AOP around Aspect, Servlet Filter or similar). That wrapper should do the following: create a unique id for the action (UUID) and put in the [MDC of your logging framework](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html). At the end of the action that id gets removed again. All other logging should include that id. Wrap you connection pool as well. Keep track on when something requested a connection, including the timestamp, the id and possibly the stacktrace (by creating and storing an exception). Log that. Every time a connection gets returned log the time it was used. Also every time a connection gets requested check if any connection is used for longer then some threshold.
5. Isolate things: Set up a second server, where you run the application. Does it have the same problem? Run some parts only on one of the two servers, do they still both have the problem? Continue to exclude candidates until only one is left.

Comment: Your sample code in #3 is missing `try/catch` blocks around each of the `close()` calls. If the calls to `close()` to throw an exception, it will (a) mask the original exception and (b) if the `Statement.close()` fails, the connection will not be closed.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz exactly, that is the point of the example code.

Comment: that makes the code fragile. You should have two nested try/catch blocks in your existing try/catch block.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Sorry, but are you reading what I write? This was the point of the example. This is the kind of problem the OP should be looking for. That's why it has a comment: // this will never happen if stmnt.close throws an exception

Comment: Yes, I'm reading what you wrote. Just documenting that it won't happen isn't good enough. You should have a nested try/catch in there that *guarantees* it still happens if `stmnt.close` throws an exception. Also, if `stmnt.close()` (or `con.close()`) throws an exception, any original in-flight exception will be lost, masking what might be a bigger problem. I just think if you're going to show an example of the "right" way to do this kind of code, you may as well post an example that's ... well, *right*.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz For heavens sake. I told it over and over again: This was never intended as an example of the right way! It is an example of the wrong way. The kind of code the OP should look for, because it might be the cause of his problems.

Answer (score 2):

If I am faced with such an issue, I would try my best to get a thread dump of when the maxActive connections reaches 50. 
You could try increasing this maxActive limit to check if the application has a higher peak.

I would also configure tomcat to use a connection pool provider such as c3p0, if it is not already being used. I would then create a custom hook class as described in the following section:
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers

With this custom class keep a running counter of the connections being acquired and released. When this number is near or at the limit, initiate a thread dump programmatically. This can be done as described in the following page:
http://crunchify.com/how-to-generate-java-thread-dump-programmatically/
Analyze this thread dump to check the source of the connections.

This information will not only be useful for your current issue but also for troubleshooting future performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

I built a [Connection Pool monitoring tool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool), called FlexyPool and it might help you finding out the culprit. It supports TomcatCP as well and you can correlate its metrics with other logs your currently using,

The `connection lease time histogram` should tell you how much time a connection is hold, meaning you might have some slow queries.

The `concurrent connections histogram` tells you how many connections are used at one and if you have less than 50 then you have a connection leakage problem.